# Laravel 5.2. Почему массив не передается в шаблон

Tags: laravel

Метод

```
  public function admin()
{
    //$users = DB::select("SELECT * FROM `fullusers`");
    $users = fulluser::all();
    dump($users);
    //return view('panel',$users);
    return view('panel')->with($users);
}
```

В шаблоне всегда ноль

```
{{ isset($users) ? 1 :0 }}
```

Пробовал просто извлечь из БД, при этом сonfig\database

```
'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
```

а сейчас пробую через модель, выдает ошибку
Illegal offset type

Comment: `return view('panel')->with('users', $users);`

Comment: @Zippbl4, Спасибо!